# Python Adding UUIDs to list to be appended to JSON/Dict object

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following code so far:

```
for endpoint in endpoints:
   post_aga = APINSRRequestsRouter()
   response_obj_aga = post_aga.send_aga_post_request(endpoint)

   if response_obj_aga:
      if response_obj_aga[0] == "201":
         id = response_obj_aga[1]["ACK"]["id"]

         #dictionary with list code here
```

response_obj_aga is a list object containing a string, and a json object, as exampled:

```
['200', {'ACK': {'message': 'something happened', 'id': '319711da-20fd-4c94-bf8b-04735b435dd1'}}]
```

What I'm looking to do is every time I get a response_obj_aga object back containing an id, I want to apend that id to a list in a dictionary so I can save it as a JSON object in my database.  So lets say I am expecting 3 separate responses, and have the following data:

```
['200', {'ACK': {'message': 'something happened', 'id': '17d362ae-a796-40fd-a1c3-0ff64e6f62e0'}}]

['200', {'ACK': {'message': 'something happened', 'id': '54e63ab8-aa1b-4d6f-a570-6ee7e52e2318'}}]

['200', {'ACK': {'message': 'something happened', 'id': 'b0a8ad20-b3e6-4100-963e-0f5e7f7e51f5'}}]
```

What I want to get at the end of my loop would be something like this:

```
{
  "ids": [
        "17d362ae-a796-40fd-a1c3-0ff64e6f62e0",
        "54e63ab8-aa1b-4d6f-a570-6ee7e52e2318",
        "b0a8ad20-b3e6-4100-963e-0f5e7f7e51f5"
  ]
}
```

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a template object and append the IDs to it as the responses are read.

Working example:

```py
import json

responses = [['200', {'ACK': {'message': 'something happened', 'id': '17d362ae-a796-40fd-a1c3-0ff64e6f62e0'}}],
             ['200', {'ACK': {'message': 'something happened', 'id': '54e63ab8-aa1b-4d6f-a570-6ee7e52e2318'}}],
             ['200', {'ACK': {'message': 'something happened', 'id': 'b0a8ad20-b3e6-4100-963e-0f5e7f7e51f5'}}]]

result = {'ids':[]}

for response in responses:
    result['ids'].append(response[1]['ACK']['id'])

print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
{
  "ids": [
    "17d362ae-a796-40fd-a1c3-0ff64e6f62e0",
    "54e63ab8-aa1b-4d6f-a570-6ee7e52e2318",
    "b0a8ad20-b3e6-4100-963e-0f5e7f7e51f5"
  ]
}
```

What your code should look like:

```py
result = {'ids':[]}

for endpoint in endpoints:
   post_aga = APINSRRequestsRouter()
   response_obj_aga = post_aga.send_aga_post_request(endpoint)

   if response_obj_aga:
      if response_obj_aga[0] == "201":
         id_ = response_obj_aga[1]["ACK"]["id"]

         result['ids'].append(id_)
```

Note: `id` is a built-in function in Python and shouldn't be used for a variable name.